# Where would the where clause go in this sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0830d)

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "totals"
1       3       0           US          0       //Desired output 5
2       10      1           US          0
3       10      1           US          0
4       10      1           US          0
5       10      1           US          0
6       10      1           US          0

7       3       0           US          0       //Desired output 5
8       10      7           US          0
9       10      7           US          0
10      10      7           US          0
11      10      7           US          0
12      10      7           US          0

13      3       0           SE          0       //Desired output 1
14      10      13          SE          0

15      3       0           SE          0       //Desired output 3
16      10      15          SE          0
17      10      15          SE          0
18      10      15          SE          0
```

In the above table, I'm trying to update the parent with the count of its children `(how many children a parent has. I'll supply the parent id and country)`.

The parents are `type 3` and children are `type 10` and the country codes are at the side.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
$parent = 10;
$country = 'US';

`select count(*) as totalChildren, parent, country where type= 10 and parent = $parent and country = $country` then
`update table set totals = totalChildren where parent = parent from above and country = country from above`.
```

I currently use the below SQL to update the entire table, but if i need to update only a praticular parent where should I put the where clause in the below sql. I'm a little confused with this.

```
UPDATE  likesd a // where parent = $parent and country = $country - where should this go?
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  country, parent, count(id) totalChildren
            FROM    likesd
            WHERE   type = 10
            GROUP   BY parent
        ) b ON a.id=b.parent and a.country = b.country
SET     a.totals = b.totalChildren
WHERE   a.type = 3 and a.id = b.parent and a.country = b.country;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have a single child to parent relationship, this should work:

```
UPDATE likesd l
JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(1) cnt, parent
  FROM likesd 
  WHERE parent = ?
  GROUP BY parent
  ) l2 ON l.id = l2.parent
SET l.totals = l2.cnt
```

[Update Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97d4c/1)

I'm assuming ID is your primary key, thus not needing to supply the country.  If you do need to though, place it in the `WHERE` clause in the subquery.